# MSACCCESS Form Labels disappear after assigning ADO.recordset to form.recordset

Tags: ms-access

I assign an ADO.recordset to the form.recordset of my main 'account' form, the code runs within a 'control panel' form.

Everything on the account form disappears, I do a form.refresh and a <s>subform</s> **TabControl**, with all controls on it re-appear, along with the **fields** on the main part of the form.  The labels on the main part of the form won't reappear until I move to the next record.

How can I force the labels to reappear?

```
public function fnProcessSQL_RetrieveADO(sSQL, ByRef rs As ADODB.Recordset) {
If Not dbReturnRecordset Is Nothing Then
    dbReturnRecordset.Close
    Set dbReturnRecordset = Nothing
End If

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open sSQL, conn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
}
```

---

```
Public dbAccounts As ADODB.Recordset

sql = "SQL Code for rows I want returned"

If fnProcessSQL_RetrieveADO(sql, dbAccounts) = True Then
    Set Forms!frmAccount.Form.Recordset = dbAccounts
End If
```

Comment: It's apparent that you have problems with labels, but technically your sentences are incomplete and contradictory.  It says that labels *"... **reappear**, along with the labels on the **main part of the form**... but the labels on the **main part of the form** won't reappear..."*  So which is it, do the main form labels reappear or not?

Comment: Also, you say that you do a *"form.refresh and a subform"*.  Do you mean a "subform.refresh"?  Finally, it is always best to show a snippet of the code, not always because it is necessary, but it makes it easier for others to copy and edit your code as part of an answer... and it could indicate that something is amiss if the behavior is not what you want/expect.  (Make it convenient for others to help you by ensuring sentences are complete and that you post code to work with.)

Comment: Why set form Recordset property instead of RecordSource property?

Comment: Apologies @CPerkins, one of those 'labels' should have been 'fields'. I've corrected, tidied and added code snippets.

Comment: @June7 I'm using ADO to retrieve the data rows, easiest way was to grab it as a recordset and assign it to the forms' recordset.

Comment: I have never done this and don't really understand why you use this approach. I have set RecordSource for a report, for a form I just apply filter using Filter and FilterOn properties.

Comment: You did not indicate language tag and I assumed VBA until I noticed the `{ }`. If this is VB.Net, I suppose using Recordset instead of RecordSource is reasonable. Sorry, I don't use VB.Net.